# How do I get the right URL for web scraping?

Tags: python, web-scraping, url, python-requests

I made a bot to scrape the price of a sneaker, and I was in trouble with getting the price, someone here helped me with the right URL for the request and scraping work.

url original of the product: https://www.vans.com.br/tenis-ultrarange-rapidweld-black-white/p/1003500430051U?gad_source=1
url modified to scrap: .com.br/arezzocoocc/v2/vans/products/1003500430051U/dynamic-product-fields?fields=DYNAMIC_FIELDS_PDP
new url I want to modify: https://www.nike.com.br/tenis-nike-pegasus-40-masculino-025803.html?cor=ID

and here is my code to find this sneaker price:

```
import requests
import smtplib
import email.message
import ssl

headers = {
    "User-Agent": "Mozilla/5.0 (X11; Ubuntu; Linux x86_64; rv:121.0) Gecko/20100101 Firefox/121.0"
}
def get_product_data(url, number):
    try:
        response = requests.get(url, headers=headers)
        response.raise_for_status()
        data = response.json()
        return next((c for c in data.get("colorOptions", []) if c["code"] == number), None)
    except requests.RequestException as e:
        print(f"Error fetching product data for {number}: {e}")
        return None

def send_email(product_name, product_price, receiver_email):
    subject = "Price Drop Alert!"
    body_msg = f'''The price of {product_name} has dropped to {product_price}.'''
    message = f"Subject: {subject}\n\n{body_msg}"

    sender = '<REDACTED>'
    password = '<REDACTED>'
    receiver = '<REDACTED>'

    context = ssl.create_default_context()

    with smtplib.SMTP_SSL('smtp.gmail.com', 465, context=context) as server:
        server.login(sender, password)

        server.sendmail(sender, receiver, message.encode('utf-8'))

number1 = "1003500430051U"
number2 = "1002001070011U"

url1 = f"https://www.vans.com.br/arezzocoocc/v2/vans/products/{number1}/dynamic-product-fields?fields=DYNAMIC_FIELDS_PDP"
url2 = f"https://www.vans.com.br/arezzocoocc/v2/vans/products/{number2}/dynamic-product-fields?fields=DYNAMIC_FIELDS_PDP"

product1 = get_product_data(url1, number1)
product2 = get_product_data(url2, number2)

if product1 and "price" in product1:
    productprice1 = product1["price"]["value"]
    print(product1["name"], productprice1)

if product2 and "price" in product2:
    print(product2["name"], product2["price"]["value"])

try:
    data1 = requests.get(url1, headers=headers).json()
    data2 = requests.get(url2, headers=headers).json()
except requests.RequestException as e:
    print(f"Error fetching product data: {e}")

for c in data1["colorOptions"]:
    if c["code"] == number1:
        productprice1 = data1["price"]["value"]
        print(c["name"], productprice1)
        break

for c in data2["colorOptions"]:
    if c["code"] == number2:
        print(c["name"], data2["price"]["value"])
        break

if productprice1 and productprice1 < 600:
    send_email(product1["name"], productprice1, 'vini.damatta17@gmail.com')
```

I tried making the new url into this: https://www.nike.com.br/tenis-nike-pegasus-40-masculino-025803/dynamic-product-fields?fields=DYNAMIC_FIELDS_PDP

and it didn't work, if someone could help with how I can get this in any URL, it would be very helpful to my scrap program, so I can know how to search for any product when needed.

Comment: `vans.com.br` and `nike.com.br` are completely different web pages. They use different URLs/methods from where they fetch data. You have to make parser for each web page separately.

Comment: Yes, as Andrej said. You will likely have to define a new function (with authorisation) for Nike. [This link](https://engineering.nike.com/cerberus/components/) might help.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

As it's a different site (Nike, not Vans) - won't you need to be authorised to use that site?

```
number1 = "1003500430051U"
number2 = "1002001070011U"
url1 = f"https://www.vans.com.br/arezzocoocc/v2/vans/products/{number1}/dynamic-product-fields?fields=DYNAMIC_FIELDS_PDP"
url2 = f"https://www.vans.com.br/arezzocoocc/v2/vans/products/{number2}/dynamic-product-fields?fields=DYNAMIC_FIELDS_PDP"
```

You also provided parameters to the Vans URL's. But not the Nike one.

```
number3 = ?
url3 = f"https://www.nike.com.br/tenis-nike-pegasus-40-masculino-025803.html?cor=ID"
```

Changing this line:

```
product1 = get_product_data(url1, number1)
product2 = get_product_data(url3, number2)
```

With

```
url3 = f"https://www.nike.com.br/tenis-nike-pegasus-40-masculino-025803.html?cor=ID"
```

Yields the error:

```
Error fetching product data for 1002001070011U: 403 Client Error: Forbidden for url: https://www.nike.com.br/tenis-nike-pegasus-40-masculino-025803.html?cor=ID
Tennis Ultrarange Rapidweld Black White 549.99
Tennis Old Skool Black White 399.99
```

Which implies it is an authorisation error. You may need an API Key or some other form of authorisation for Nike.

Comment: Yes, I think the right way is with an API, but I just wanted to know how to do this, and with the url3 that you write, it doesn't work, it need to be a dynamic field page, that's what I am not knowing how to do

Comment: Not necessarily using an *API*, but the `API_KEY` might have to be added to the URL before a request can be accepted.